# How to set the value for datepicker, timepicker for each row reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-redux

I would like to know how to set  default value for the datepicker and timepicker value for each row,

I have implemented the datepicker and timepicker, in which `home.js` have state `additionalFields`, has array of values indicates the default value of datpicker and timepicker for each row.

But in my code, first array values `additionalFields` is shown for all rows, instead set the eeach array value to datepicker and timepicker
How to set default value of additionalFields for each row.

My Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-pond-qgt5o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue in binding for value of `datepicker`  you are using `index of column` instead of `row index` so you should change it as following

```
value={
                // this.state["pickdate_" + rowId] || this.defaultPickdate
                this.state["pickdate_" + rowId] ||
                this.props.rows[row.id].pickdate // changed this line
      }
```

in your code you are using `index` variable which refer to column index not row index and in all satiation its value of first row.

Comment: Youshif, when adding 2 new row, clicking on  third row delete throws error, can help ??

Comment: did you change row ids for new rows to be in the same sequence

Comment: am not changing row id for new rows

Comment: @Senthil can you save your changes to check it codesandbox

Comment: i have made changes, can you please check: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-pond-qgt5o?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: use this.props.rows.filter(r=>r.id === row.id )[0].pickdate instead of this.props.rows[ row.id].pickdate